# PHP echo new line

Tags: php, netbeans, xampp

I'm having a real problem with echo new line in my php document. I'm working on Windows Vista, XAMPP, NetBeans 7.4 and working on index.php.
When i try to make new line like

```
echo '<br>';
```

or

```
echo '<br/>';
```

it doesn't work i always display like html chars

> < br >

on screen. 
i triend diffetent types like \n and other givin in other realated topics, but no one helps me solved that problem.

I would like to mention , in other project i don't have problem with that. It's kind a burdensome problem.

SOLUTION:
guilty was my header

> header("Content-type:text/plain");

Comment: Must be echo '<br/>'; for XHTML. But I've never seen, that echo '<br>'; doesn't work.

Comment: how you are saying not working?...

Comment: Check HTTP headers, being sent thought firebug. I think, you get text/plain content type instead of HTML.

Comment: have you tried "\n" (using double quotes)? Seems like a headers issue where your content is not recognized as (X)HTML

Comment: It will work, (not </br> but <br> will sure work). Check if: 1. The extension of the file is `*.php`. 2. You are wrapping the code in `<?php?>`

Comment: yes i got it finally, it becouse of my header, i've never could belive it has such a pover.
header("Content-type:text/plain");

Answer (score -1):

Your tag is not valid. The Newline tag is "\n" or you can use Breakline tag "`<br/>`". So try this

```
echo "<br/>";
```

Comment: FWIW `<br>` is perfectly valid in HTML